# How can I change the alt+middle-mouse-button resize to alt+right-mouse-button?

Tags: compiz, mouse, resize

I love how you can resize windows by pressing alt+middle-mouse-button and drag.

Though now I got a mouse which doesn't support pressing the middle mouse button..

How do I do to change the combination from alt+middle-mouse-button to alt+right-mouse-button?

(On Ubuntu 11.04 with unity)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. **You need to get and install [ccsm](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)** (**Compiz Config Settings Manager)**.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. **Go to Window Management --> Resize window** .

   [image: CompizConfig Settings Manager]

**Note**: Changing Button2 to Button3 or 1 may give you a conflict message. If so, choose "Disable Window Menu". However, Alt+F8 Will give you the same result. [image: key binding conflict dialog]

Comment: This is just what I was looking for - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

Follow these steps:

- To open `dconf-editor`, Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `dconf-editor` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In *dconf-editor* goto: `org` ➤ `gnome` ➤ `desktop` ➤ `wm` ➤ `preferences` and enable ☑ `resize-with-right-button`.

  [image]

Comment: It works again the way I'm used to :). Thank you very much!

Comment: much better than having to install yet another settings program.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `compizconfig-settings-manager`.

If you dont already have this installed, use Software Center and search for this package.

In dash type `ccsm` and then in the Window Management section click on "Resize Window".

At the bottom of this window is "Initiate Window Resize" - you'll notice that Button2 is the default.  You can change this to whichever button you want.

Answer (score 1):

The following script extract will do just that (and works on both new Unity and old Gnome):

```
#!/bin/bash
gconftool-2 -s -t bool /apps/metacity/general/resize_with_right_button true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences resize-with-right-button true
```

I have a script that I run whenever I install a fresh Ubuntu and the above is part of it; makes it nice and easy to restore my default settings :)

Comment: This is nice. Could you share the script with the community? Thanks!

Comment: @qed the script is literally a few lines of things that look similar to the above, and almost all of them are my personal preferences; I'm not sure how useful anyone else would find it!

Comment: If no privacy is involved, I would be glad to see it, and I am sure I can learn something from it! :-)

Comment: Especially because I am also trying to make up such a script myself.

Answer (score 1):

In GNOME/Ubuntu 18, if you install GNOME Tweaks, there's a setting for that: ["Resize with secondary click"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28514/how-to-get-altright-mouse-to-resize-windows-again/491952#491952). Checking it will enable Super+RMB to resize windows, not Alt though, but hopefully [my suggestion](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/issues/116#note_396707) will be taken into account.