# How to enable alt+right click to resize window

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, resize

Been looking around and can't see to find any information on how to enable alt+right click for window resize?

**edit**

My mistake

Running Unity 12.04, I am logged in under failsafe graphics mode as i can't get my 590GX Nvidida card to boot up without being in safe, but thats another problem.

Currently, my alt+click works and i can drag windows around.

But i can't currently, alt+right-click to resize.

Comment: It should work out of the box, without modifications. Please provide more information: what desktop environment are you on (Unity/KDE/GNOME/XFCE/LXDE/...)? Did you update your installation?  Did you try to create a new user, log in as the new user and see if that works?

Comment: edited, should make more sense.

Comment: Did you check the compiz resize settings(plugin)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install compizconfig-settings-manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and run `ccsm` from the Dash or from a Terminal window.

```
ccsm
```

Click `Window Management` and `Resize Window`.

For  `| Initiate Window Resize` assign `<Alt>Button3`.

Comment: This also works for 14.04.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity 7.4.0), you have to first go to `General Options` ->  `Key bindings` and disable Window Menu (which has the same `<Alt>Button3` bindings), or change its binding. Anyway, this question is a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/55532/how-can-i-change-the-altmiddle-mouse-button-resize-to-altright-mouse-button

Comment: Related to @DanDascalescu 's comment, the CompizCongif Settings manager now disables the other binding on its own.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286724/how-to-resize-windows-with-altright-click-instead-of-altmiddle-click-in-ubuntu/296129#296129) describes a method that works in both 12.04 (and possibly older versions) as well as 12.10/13.04 with the new `gsettings`

Put this in a script and run it:

```
#!/bin/bash
gconftool-2 -s -t bool /apps/metacity/general/resize_with_right_button true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences resize-with-right-button true
```

The gconftool-2 line is for GConf based systems, and gsettings is its newer replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found:

Use `gconf-editor` and set `/apps/metacity/general`: `resize_with_right_button = true`