# How to resize windows with alt+right click instead of alt+middle click in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, window, resize

The title says it all. I want to resize windows with an right click while holding the alt key, instead of the new default alt+middle click.

I have found no way to enable this behaviour in 13.04. The gconf-Key suggested in this [solution for 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231195/how-to-enable-altright-click-to-resize-window), doesn't seem to exist any longer.