# unity 14.04 no alt+right-click resize

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

There are already a number of topics relating to the `right-click` `resize` problem but they all date to older versions of ubuntu and their respective answers and solutions did not work in my case.

So I have a 14.04 ubuntu that has `ubuntu-desktop` installed with the `unity desktop`.

The `alt+left-click` move window works flawlessly and I would like to use the `alt + right-click` to resize the window.

Upon noticing that it does not work I looked in the settings menu and could find the actions in the keyboard settings but for some reason, both have different accelerators. The action to move the window is set to `alt+F7` but `alt+left-click` works so it must be set somewhere.

Does anyone here know where this setting can be changed apart from the keyboard settings menu as it does not allow mouse clicks to be registered as shortcuts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the alt+middle-mouse-button resize to alt+right-mouse-button?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55532/how-can-i-change-the-altmiddle-mouse-button-resize-to-altright-mouse-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting should be set in ccsm. If ccsm isn't installed, install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins
```

Now, open ccsm:

```
ccsm &
```

Click on <kbd>General Options</kbd> and then navigate to the **key bindings** tab.

Scroll down to **Resize Window** and enable this plugin. It should already be set to **Alt + Button2**.

Comment: I was looking for the window resize option, not the window menu one but disabling the latter and setting window resize to button3 did the trick. Thank you for the help.

Comment: There is no "window resize" among the key bindings in the Unity 7.4.0 that comes with Ubuntu 16.04. Also, this question is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/55532/how-can-i-change-the-altmiddle-mouse-button-resize-to-altright-mouse-button

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner to do it. Open a terminal and paste this:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/resize-with-right-button true
```

No need to install `ccsm`.